# Magento : Change date format for an attribute

Tags: magento, date, attributes, format

The date format for my `begin_date` attribute is displaying like : `2015-04-25 00:00:00`
and i want it like : `25 04 2015`

I tried :

```
<?php 
    echo $this->helper('core')->formatDate(getbegin_date(), Mage_Core_Model_Locale::FORMAT_TYPE_SHORT); 
?>
```

But it don't work.

Answer (score 1):

Here is how you can format the time (in PHP). If you need more reference then check this page: [Playing with Dates in Magento](http://www.blog.magepsycho.com/playing-with-dates-in-magento/)

```
$current_time = Mage::getModel('core/date')->timestamp(time()); 
echo $date = date('d m Y', $current_time);
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, but when i use your code, i have the current time but i need to display my date attribute with the good format. I tried all the solutions of your link but i dont find solutions

Comment: The date is basic PHP function, here's reference to how to use them:
 [date reference](http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_date_date.asp)..

So for example if you wish to have both date and time in "proper format". Then you could do something like following:

`date('d.m.Y H:i', $current_time);`